# jquery function using selectors as variables

Tags: jquery

So I have a particular function that needs to repeated again and again. So I thought I would make just one function that can be re-used.

```
function validate_form(field,validate) {
field.focus(function(){
    $(validate).css('margin-left','206px');
    $(validate).fadeIn();
    $(validate).animate({ 
            'marginLeft': '286px'
            }, 'fast');
    name        = $(field).val();
    alert(name);        
});
}
```

to call the function I would use something like

```
validation_form('#contact_name','#contact_name_validate');
```

So the idea here is to pass through the particular selectors required into the function, but I just cant seem to get it working. 
Is there some special way to pass through selectors when they are used as variables in a function?

Answer (score 5):

If the `field` parameter contains a selector you have to pass it to the `jQuery()` function:

```
$(field).focus(function(){
```

Note also that you can make your function more efficient by chaining the different methods that you want to use with `$(validate)`:

```
function validate_form(field, validate) {
    $(field).focus(function () {
        $(validate).css('margin-left', '206px')
                   .fadeIn()
                   .animate({'marginLeft': '286px'}, 'fast');
        name = this.value;
        alert(name);
    });
}
```

At the point inside the focus handler where you had `$(field).val()` you can use `$(this).val()` or `this.value` rather than `$(field).val()` because `this` will already be the focused element so you don't need to select it again with `$(field)`.

Comment: Oh right, I left out the $ for field, I was also calling the function by the wrong name: validate_form, not validation_form. Sloppy work!

Answer (score 1):

`field` is a string containing a selector, not a jQuery object, you need:

```
$(field).focus(function(){
    /* other stuff in here */
});
```

Incidentally, this error *should* have shown up in the JavaScript console (it does for me, in Chromium at least):

```
TypeError: Object #contact_name has no method 'focus'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the jQuery objects in instead as this will cache the jQuery objects so you are not retrieving them more than once:

```
var $field = $('#contact_name');
var $validate = $('#contact_name_validate');

validation_form($field, $validate);

function validate_form($field, $validate) {
    $field.focus(function(){
        $validate.css('margin-left','206px');
        $validate.fadeIn();
        $validate.animate({ 
            'marginLeft': '286px'
        }, 'fast');
        name = $field.val();

        alert(name);        
    });
}
```

Comment: The OP mentioned the function would be repeated "again and again", presumably with different selectors each time - are you suggesting creation of `$field` and `$validate` variables for each time?

Comment: He could just pass the selector in itself instead of creating it in a variable. The main difference/benefit is caching the objects. `validation_form($('#contact_name'), $('#contact_name_validate'));`

Comment: Or if you cache them _inside_ the function then it would work regardless of whether you passed it selector strings or jQuery objects. But for this particular function there's no need to cache at all because you can just chain the methods used on `$(validate)` and use `this.value` instead of `$(field).val()` and then each item gets retrieved only once.

Comment: Wherever he caches them it does not make a difference. I was more making the point that he should cache in general. In this situation it did not matter as much, but we do not know how his function may change in the future so it is good to teach best practice as well.